# Split form into tabs in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm developing a Django app which has database driven form fields. I've followed [this guide](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) which seems to work so far.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and would like to split my fields into tabs. What would be the Django way to do this? Should I append the group label to the id of the form fields and somehow do the magic in the template? Should I use multiple forms in the same view (seems complicated)?

The end result HTML wise is to enclose the input fields in the correct div elements with the group's id [like so](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently required the very same thing.

After some research, I used [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms), which worked quite well. A more detailed instructions about the tabs (and the need of .js file for animation) can be found [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html), in the 'tabs' section.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further please? The docs don't mention the template part, among other things missing